# Android Spinner not calling onItemSelected

Tags: android, android-spinner

EDIT: I did a workaround and it SORT OF fixed my issue.
My layout for the spinner looks like

```
<LinearLayout>
    <Spinner>
    <TextView> //used as a label
</LinearLayout>
```

I removed the LinearLayout. Though the City spinner does not become auto-populated with items whenever a State is selected, I am able to manually input values for the City.

What could the linearlayout possibly do to mess up my spinner's behavior?

---

I have a registration form with multiple Edittexts and 3 spinners at the bottom namely State, City, Area.

What I want to be able to do is the following

1. onItemSelect a State, City and Area will show the first items in their list
2. onItemSelect a City, Area will show the first item in its list
3. onItemSelect an Area, it will show the item I selected.

Code is working fine on Kitkat. But on JellyBean and below, whenever I select a State, the other spinners do not show anything. After selecting a State, when you click on the City, it will show correct dataset, however when I click on an item the spinner remains blank. (onItemSelected does not fire.)

The weird part is that, whenever the spinners misbehave, if I click on one of the Edittexts in my view (softKeyboard will be shown) > Press back button > Spinner works. I'm not sure if it has something to do with focus? But I already tried to set the spinners to focusable and focusableInTouchMode then request focus, but to no avail.

this is how I set the adapters and content of the spinners

```
state.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
    state.setSelection(0, false);
    state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            stateSelection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            cityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, getDistinctCity(stateSelection));
            cityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
            city.setAdapter(cityAdapter);

            areaAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, new String[]{});
            areaAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
            area.setAdapter(areaAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            citySelection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            areaAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, getDistinctArea(stateSelection, citySelection));
            areaAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
            area.setAdapter(areaAdapter);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    area.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            areaSelection = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            postalSelection = getDistinctPostal(stateSelection, citySelection, areaSelection);
            postal.setText(postalSelection);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

If anyone can explain to me why the spinners are behaving like this, or possibly lead me to the right direction, that would be awesome. Thank you

Comment: Try calling notifyDataSetChanged() on city's and area's adapters after adding them to the components they provide with data.